# I work as Software Enginner & Consultant for a Person who has lot of Source of Income few of them is haram is my salary also haram?

Tags: halal-haram, source-identification

I was initially hired to create a website for an individual's commercial display business, involving the sale of products like big TVs. Impressed with my work, he offered me a monthly income, considering his diverse business ventures in properties and, later, event management. The events include activities like making sets, hiring DJs, serving alcohol, and free mixing. Despite my role being limited to managing servers, emails, and websites, I wonder if my income from this association is considered haram.

however i dont have any other source of income as of now and i have doubt and i want to leave this company and finding a new job however i am not getting any job and i have a family with wife mom sister and a baby.

So until i find a halal job is this job is considered haram for me.